# How to update data frame column in Spark

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in which there are 2 json columns. I need to update j2 column based on j1 column. If j2 column's element is null then pick the element value from j1 column. j1 is JSON string and j2 is JSON array.

input dataframe,

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|         j1                |              j2                       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|{"A": "50", "B": "30"}     | [{"A": null}, {"A": "20", "B": null}] |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

output

```
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|          j1            |              j2                       |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|{"A": "50", "B": "30"}  | [{"A":"50"}, {"A": "20", "B": "30"}]  |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

spark version : 2.4.0 language: scala

Comment: Can you please post the sample code to create the source dataframe?

Comment: column j2 = collect_list(to_json(struct("A", "B"))) and j1 = to_json(struct("A", "B")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace function to get required result.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val inDF = Seq(("""{"A": "50", "B": "30"} """, """[{"A": null}, {"A": "20", "B": null}]""")).toDF("j1", "j2")

  inDF.withColumn("A", get_json_object('j1, "$.A"))
    .withColumn("B", get_json_object('j1, "$.B"))
    .withColumn("j2", regexp_replace('j2, lit("\"A\": null"), 
      concat(lit("\"A\": "), lit("\""), 'A, lit("\""))))
    .withColumn("j2", regexp_replace('j2, lit("\"B\": null"),
      concat(lit("\"B\": "), lit("\""), 'B, lit("\""))))
    .drop("A", "B")
    .show(false)

+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|j1                     |j2                                   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|{"A": "50", "B": "30"} |[{"A": "50"}, {"A": "20", "B": "30"}]|
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I like your idea. I was thinking to parse the json object and put value from other json string. I think it is more easy. Thanks